# Непонятность в тестах

Tags: лексика

Часть B. Ответы заданий В1-В6 вносятся прописными буквами, за исключением имен собственных, **которые вносятся согласно правилам русского языка.**

Объясните, пожалуйста,как понять выделенное место и как писать ответ - все слова с прописной или только первое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это онлайн-тест, там возможно написание всего слова прописными буквами.

Ответами на задания 1-6 будут слова или словосочетания, а не предложения, вот их и нужно писать  прописными буквами, а если  в словосочетании есть имена собственные, тогда оба слова с прописной, а сами слова  строчными, чтобы показать,что имя собственное с большой буквы.

Укажите происхождение подчеркнутого слова ... (ЗАИМСТВОВАННОЕ).